# android SQLiteDatabase.insert vs executeSQL

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-injection

I am working on an app which has multiple db insert/update queries and throughout the app i have used

```
SQLiteDatabase.insert(String table, String nullColumnHack, ContentValues values)
```

method for inserting any data to any table. What i mean by this is i create a ContentValues object and put all my values as key/value pair inside this object and pass it on to this this method.

```
contentValues.put("col1", valueCol1);
contentValues.put("col2", valueCol2);
contentValues.put("col3", valueCol3);
```

So just wanted to check if this way of inserting records to a sqlite table is better or is it better to use executeSQL [ From SQLinjection standpoint]. I do understand as per the documentation here

```
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL(java.lang.String)][1]
```

that its recommended to use insert over execSQL. **But which is more prone to SQLInjections if at all one is.** Any inputs/suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the page that you linked

> "Instead, you're encouraged to use insert(String, String,
>   ContentValues), update(String, ContentValues, String, String[]), et
>   al, when possible."

you should use `insert()` when it is possible.

> To avoid SQL injection requests, you need to clearly delineate between
>   the SQL statement and the data it includes. The ContentProvider’s
>   query(), update(), and delete()methods and Activity’s managedQuery()
>   method all support parameterization. These methods all take the
>   “String[] selectionArgs” parameter, a set of values that get
>   substituted into the query string in place of “?” characters, in the
>   order the question marks appear. This provides clear separation
>   between the content of the SQL statement in the “selection” parameter
>   and the data being included. [Mobile Application Security]

So, `insert()` method like `update()` or `delete()` should be sql-injection free.

You should always use parametrized query methods, supported by Content Provider:

> When accessing a content provider, use parameterized query methods
>   such as query(), update(), and delete() to avoid potential SQL
>   injection from untrusted sources. Note that using parameterized
>   methods is not sufficient if the selection argument is built by
>   concatenating user data prior to submitting it to the method.

reference [here](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html)

Comment: Thanks Joseph for your answer.

Comment: It's noted at the end, but still ... they're not automatically "sql-injection free", but you do need to use them correctly (static query, and parameters only go into parameters array).